# Accessing knockout js selected option inside a computed variable

Tags: knockout.js

I want to create a computed observable which will return the percentage value:

```
self.percentage = ko.computed(function(){
            var percentage = (self.amount() * self.selectedItem().itemVAT)/100;
            return percentage;
        });
```

**I keep getting - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'itemVAT' of undefined.**

```
var items = function(item_name, item_number, item_vat) {
        this.itemName = item_name;
        this.itemNumber = item_number;
        this.itemVAT = item_vat;
    };
```

An Ajax call is used to create new items and assign them to select box using options binding like following:

```
this.availableItems = ko.observableArray();
this.selectedItem = ko.observable();

jQuery.each(data, function(i, val) {
                    self.availableItems .push(new items(val.item_name,val.item_number,val.item_vat));
                });


<select class="form-control" name="item_name" id="item_name" data-bind = "options: availableItems,
                       optionsText: 'itemName',
                       value: selectedItem,
                       optionsCaption: 'Choose...'"></select>
```

Comment: Can you provide the code where you define `availableItems` and `selectedItem`?

Comment: @Olga Please check the modified code in question.

Comment: I am slow. Working pen here http://codepen.io/sirinity/pen/OVEXrJ =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By specifying `optionsCaption`, you allow `selectedItem` to be undefined. Test for that, and you're ok.

```
  self.percentage = ko.computed(function() {
    if (self.selectedItem() === undefined) return 0;
    var percentage = (self.amount() * self.selectedItem().itemVAT) / 100;
    return percentage;
  });
```